# Read from several sockets: single thread with select vs. multi-thread read

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp, udp

I am designing some protocol based on TCP and UDP and I need to receive simultaneously data from several clients: each client will send these data via 2 sockets (TCP and UDP). I doubt how to implement the server. I am going through several options:

1. To implement all reads from all sockets in one thread using select() (1 select).
2. To process all UDP sockets in one threads and TCP – in another (2 selects).
3. To run each receive in separate thread, the sockets are in blocking mode.

My goal is to achieve maximum throughput on UDP sockets (minimum lost datagrams) and minimum processing time on TCP sockets. My opinion that on multicore CPU the option #3 may give more efficiency. Am I correct?

Comment: You're designing an implementation, not a protocol. I suggest you do it the easy way first and then see if you really have a  problem to solve.

Comment: `select` gives you reasonable timeout and also can wait for pending signals (see `signalfd`). You could always move processing to other thread after `select` has awoken. Moreover, it is always a good practice to have any means of stopping a running thread. Blocking `read` won't give you this.

Comment: @EJP, in fact I am designing new protocol above TCP & UDP. But my question is about an implementation

Comment: @ zoska 1. I want to do very simple implementation working in Linux and Windows. 2. Sorry, didn't understand: why blocking read differs from stopping thread?

Comment: There are way too many factors that go into this kind of decisions to give a simple once-size-fits-all answer.  

My advice: Do some more research (there are tons of free online articles as well as entire books on network programming), build some "toy" applications to see what works well and what suits your skill / comfort zone, and get back to SO.com when you have more specific questions/problems.

Comment: Does the server have only one UDP socket or one UDP socket per client?

Comment: @Steve Actually, it will be 1 (one) UDP socket for all clients because of all clients will send their UDP data to one server's port. Obviously, for TCP it must be allocated 1 socket per client.

Answer (score 1):

I would have one thread per TCP connection and one UDP thread.